# How to convert an html webpage to a picture

Tags: java, browser, html

How to convert an html webpage to a picture  like google preview.

Is there a Java library permitting this?

Is there a command-line argument to call browsers to make them convert a web page into a picture .png for instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/), you can create a simple window with a [QWebView](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwebview.html) (this is webkit under the covers), and then use QWidget::render() method to get QPixmap, and then convert it to QImage.

Qt is C++, but [python](http://www.pyside.org/) and [java](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/category/qt-jambi/) bindings exist also.

Answer (score 0):

[See here](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/06/26/generating-pdfs-with-flying-saucer-and-itext.html). It shows that [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) and [FlyingSaucer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer//) (xhtmlrenderer) have such options.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/swing/Print.shtml

Here's a way to do it!